# Why is Telethon so slow to send files?

Tags: api, telegram, telethon

I am using https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/ to send a file to TG, when sending a **400mb** file it takes about **~10 minutes**, although my internet speed is **100 megabits**, when sending I indicated *part_size_kb = 512*, there are some ideas?

Comment: Communication with Telegram is encrypted, and unless libssl or [`cryptg`](https://pypi.org/project/cryptg/) are available, encryption will be done within Python, which is extremely slow (see [Optional Dependencies](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/installation.html?highlight=cryptg#optional-dependencies)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that data decryption is done in C and not in Python (much faster)

```
 pip install cryptg
```